# how to add and edit data at the same time into local list

Tags: flutter, dart

i have these fields from `Firstore` doc

```
'name': 'Alex'
'age': 20
'product': 'cars'
```

and here i get data

```
List <QueryDocumentSnapshot> finalResultsForMessgse = [] ;
 future getData(){ 
 FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("product").get().then((value) {
 value.docs.forEach((data) { 
 finalResultsForMessgse.add(data); // here it will add data as written 
 exactly in firstore into my local list
```

but how can manual edit fields into my local list ..like following

```
   finalResultsForMessgse.add(
      'name':value.get('name')+'add extra Letters'
      'age':value.get('age')+'add extra Letters'
      'product':value.get('product')+'add extra Letters'
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

use `List<dynamic> finalResultsForMessgse = [];` for final result list.

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('product').get().then((value) {
  value.docs.forEach((data) {
    var doc = data.data();

    finalResultsForMessgse.add({
      'name': '${doc['name']} + add extra Letters',
      'age': '${doc['age']} + add extra Letters',
      'product': '${doc['product']} + add extra Letters',
    });
  });
});
```

To show the result list:

```
for (var item in finalResultsForMessgse) Text('${item['name']}'),
```

Comment: thanks but in my case i should use List <QueryDocumentSnapshot> finalResultsForMessgse = [] ; and not dynamic

Comment: I think ```QueryDocumentSnapshot``` gives data read, but if there is a way to do it I'm also looking for that answer